Conflicting Input File in Next JS
I have a component that has two input file type to upload two images.
<input type="file" name="passport" id="passport" onChange={handleImageChange} />
<input type="file" name="result" id="result" onChange={handleImageChange} />

As it is above, the input is not clickable, but when i change the id="upload" for the two, it will be clickable but only of input file receive the data.
How can I make the two receive data?
This is my onChange function:
  const handleImageChange = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = event.target.name;
    let file_reader = new FileReader();
    // Get the actual file itself
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    file_reader.onload = () => {
      setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    };
    file_reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

I have my state as:
 const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    passport: '',
    result: '',
  });

